# Scale along face normal

Tags: normals, scale, transform-orientation

When trying to scale the fire object along the top face normal changing the transformation orientation doesn't get the desperately wanted end result. The local and global axis will not align with my top face normal. What actions should be taken to scale along a rotated axis (that aligns with the top face normal)?

My suggestion was to have the X axle rotated and of course any axis will do...

[image]

Comment: Did you tried with a custm trasform orientation (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#custom-orientations)?

Comment: Custom transform orientation is pointing me in the right direction! The Axis are now pointing the right direction. Still scaling issues since scaling on Z-axis does also scale the X and Y axis and therefor enlarges my mesh.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I'm clear on what your issue is. But any time you want to create a custom transform orientation, you can follow the instructions given by Carlo in the link to the Blender manual above easily enough. However, if you also want that custom transform orientation to be aligned with a face normal, you can press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>NUMPAD7</kbd> to force your current camera view to instantly snap to a facing that views the currently selected polygon face head-on, allowing you to look straight down its normal's z-axis. Once this camera orientation is achieved, you can create a new custom transform orientation based on it. Then you can transform along that face's normal z axis, no matter how the object it belongs to is oriented in space.

Comment: There are several problems at the same time: not able to get the direction correct (as steted above), not being able to scale on only one direction. Therefor the object is enlarged on every axis. Probably several things have gone wrong during modeling (i.e. applying all transformations, parenting, etc). In a few days I will start all over again so I can give you back what helped most. Custom transform orientation had helped me most.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Looking forward to finding out what you eventually discover.

Answer (score 0):

Having tried the Custom transform orientation worked for the first problem being not able to scale along the correct (face normal) direction. So the scaling worked better but the object was also scaling along the other axis so the who object got distorted. I probably applied scale and rotation. Since reversing rotation and scale etc also did not give the proper outcome I decided it was better to start modeling from scratch since the object was very simple. That was the fastest resolution, but now I didn't learn what the actual root-cause is. Probably going to learn that later on, since it will happen again.
I enjoyed having this experience and learned about custom transformation orientation, snapping camera view and that it is sometimes faster to start all over again and create a model that has all faces joint correctly (not having faces collapsed into the mesh).
Next time I will attach the blend file so it is easier to troubleshoot.